# Change diagonal of a set data frames in nested lists

Tags: r

I have a couple of data frames in a list nested in another list. I want to change the diagonal of the data frames to NA's.

I tried this `a <- lapply(ATS,function(x) lapply(x, function(x) diag(x) <- NA))`

but the data frames inside turned to logicals equal to NA.

How can I change the diagonal the data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to return the `x` after the assingment

```
lapply(ATS,function(x) lapply(x, function(x) {diag(x) <- NA; x}))
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. But why? If I wanted to sum the number b to all data frames, lapply(ATS,function(x) lapply(x, function(x) x + b)) would work perfectly without { ... ; x }

Comment: @David In the example, you are assigning to a value i.e .`NA` and it returns that value instead of the actual x.  While in the one in the comments, you are transforming 'x' to a new one.  Here, even if you do the assignment, it would return the value as the same length